# Premiere 2017: First Keyframe Works Third Does Not

Tags: premiere, animation

I am trying to change the scale and position of the video with keyframes in one of my videos. I turn on animation for both scale and position and it adds a keyframe. I make the adjustments in scale and position. It changes at that point of course. I move the play head to the next appropriate position and add another keyframe at the point, so that it stays the same up until that point. Then add a third set of keyframes in the next frame over. I try to make adjustments on both scale and position, nothing, absolutely nothing happens. It's ignoring any change I make, utterly and completely ignoring me. Nothing in the video preview changes. I can change the scale to 1000, it's like I'm not doing anything. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]